# Julia PyPlot ymin seems to be ignored or overridden

Tags: matplotlib, julia

This is my plotting algorithm

```
function plotValues(x::Vector{Float64}, values::Vector{Float64}, frameCount::Union{Int64, Void} = nothing; ylabelName::String = "BER")
  dpi::Int64 = 96
  PyPlot.figure(figsize=(1920/dpi, 1080/dpi))

  PyPlot.ylim(ymax=17)
  PyPlot.ylim(top=17)
  PyPlot.ylim(ymin=-17)
  PyPlot.ylim(bottom=-17)

  PyPlot.xlabel("SNR")
  PyPlot.ylabel(ylabelName)
  if nothing != frameCount
    PyPlot.title("Frames transmitted: $frameCount")
  end
  PyPlot.grid(b=true, which="major", color="b", linestyle="-")
  PyPlot.grid(b=true, which="minor", color="b", linestyle="--")

  PyPlot.ylim(ymax=17)
  PyPlot.ylim(top=17)
  PyPlot.ylim(ymin=-17)
  PyPlot.ylim(bottom=-17)

  PyPlot.semilogy(x, values)

  PyPlot.ylim(ymax=17)
  PyPlot.ylim(top=17)
  PyPlot.ylim(ymin=-17)
  PyPlot.ylim(bottom=-17)

  PyPlot.show()
end
```

Now I set at multiple points, because it is not clear to my how pyplot works internaly, that the bottom/ymin should be -17. But when I look at the result it looks like this

[image]

I know that none of my values is 0 or goes below 0, so the bottom of this graph can not be 0 (but close to it). But the top is 17 and when I change ymax or top to be something else it adjusts itself towards it. How can I make PyPlot not ignore my ymin?

Comment: it's no ignoring it. It's just doesn't know how to display negative values in the log scale. I don't think there's a way of showing the plot for negative values as there's no such thing as a log of negative number.

Comment: btw, it's enough to set the limits once at the end of the function as such: `ylim(ymax = 17)`

Comment: @niczky12 I guess that is an explanation, it still makes the graph look bad.